# SUM values in last row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

I have table with values

```
    +--------+------------+-------------+
    |  XPK   | Money      | NumOfDevices|
    +--------+------------+-------------+
    |      1 | 1000       | 2           | 
    |      2 | 2000       | 3           |
    |      3 | 3000       | 4           |
    +--------+------------+-------------+
```

Need to sum all values and to enter the asterisk "*" in entire row to separate TOTAL Values from other values, so result need to look something like this

```
        +--------+------------+-------------+
        |  XPK   | Money      | NumOfDevice |
        +--------+------------+-------------+
        |      1 | 1000       | 2           | 
        |      2 | 2000       | 3           |
        |      3 | 3000       | 4           |
        |***********************************|
        | TOTAL  | 6000       | 9           |
        +--------+------------+-------------+
```

Any idea ?

Comment: This is not something you should be handling on the database end...  Are you looking for a way to give the totals, or are the asterisks *really* that important?

Comment: Simplest solution: use UNION (first query would list the contents of the table, then a union that would add the "****" and then a union that will sum the values (note: all results MUST be converted to VARCHAR).

Comment: I will avoid asterisk, but definitely need totals at the end

Comment: What DBMS are you using?  SQL Server?  MySQL?  Oracle?  Something else?

Comment: SQL Server... need in a purpose of reporting

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way for this is to use a `UNION` selecting the totals from the table:

```
Select  Convert(Varchar (10), XPK) XPK, 
        Money,
        NumOfDevices
From    YourTable
Union
Select  'TOTAL' As XPK,
        Sum(Money),
        Sum(NumOfDevices)
From    YourTable
Order By Case When XPK = 'TOTAL' Then 1 Else 0 End, XPK
```

Another method of doing this would be to use a `GROUP BY WITH ROLLUP`

```
Select  Case When Grouping(XPK) = 1 
            Then 'TOTAL' 
            Else Convert(Varchar (10), XPK) 
        End As XPK,
        Sum(Money)          Money,
        Sum(NumOfDevices)   NumOfDevices
From    YourTable
Group By XPK With Rollup
Order By Grouping(XPK)
```

Comment: There is no guarantee that the result of the 2nd query in the union will end up as the last row. All queries without an order by statement are considered unordered.

Answer (score 0):

```
IN Table ERP System SAP 
select B.ItemCode as'Item No.',B.Dscription as'Item Description',B.Quantity,B.Price as'Sale Amt',B.LineTotal as'Total'
from ODLN A
inner join DLN1 B On A.DocEntry=B.DocEntry
union all
select 'Total',convert(nvarchar(10),sum(case when b.Dscription is not null then 1 else 0 end)),sum(b.quantity),sum(b.price),sum(b.lineTotal)
from ODLN A
inner join DLN1 B On A.DocEntry=B.DocEntry
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but cannot `with rollup` for MSSQL be used here?
Taking into consideration that you have mentioned in the comment about avoiding asterisks, but the need of TOTAL at the end:

```
    select case when XPK is null then 'TOTAL' else cast(XPK as nvarchar) end, 
           sum(Money),
           sum(NumOfDevice)
    from YOUR_TABLE
    group by XPK with rollup
```